# How to access (and modify) parameters and variables from parent scope, in nested callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can someone please explain why some variables are not passed to `readFile`'s callback, while others are?

```
// response is http response writer obj
var process = function (response, file) {

    var calculator = new mycalc.Calculator();

    var output1 = "no-error";
    var that = this;

    try {
        fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                that.output1 = "check1";
            }

            output1 = "check2";
            response.write(output1);

            // not even working with that.output1

            // more stuff will come here
        });
    } catch (e) {
        response.write(e.stack);
    }

    response.write(output1);
};
```

Issues:

- `response.write()` doesn't write within the callback function but it does write successfully from `process()` function scope.
- `output1` prints "no-error", while the expected result is "check1" or "check2"

Comment: They are all in the scope, but you are calling `response.write(output1)` before the `fs.readFile` callback is executed.

Comment: @FelixKling, is `response` in the scope too? When I do `response.write("foo");` within callback, it doesn't get printed in the browser. When I do it outside, it does. Maybe its not as simple as it seems..

Comment: It should just work like that. Every JS function is a closure and has access to all variables that are defined in the same or higher scope. It might be an issue with how `process` is supposed to be used.